# Double header guards in Visual Studio stl numeric implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, include-guards

In the `stl` implementation that comes along with Visual Studio 12.0 the `numeric` header looks like this

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _NUMERIC_
#define _NUMERIC_

// shortened for the sake of readibility
. 
.
.


#endif /* _NUMERIC_ */
```

I know that `#pragma once` is not [standard conform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards).

Nevertheless, why did they implement a double header guard?

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma once`: The same file will not be included multiple times
`include guard idiom`：uses preprocessor macro definitions to prevent multiple inclusions of the contents of the file.

According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=vs-2019)

> There's no advantage to use of both the `include guard` idiom and
>   `#pragma once` in the same file. The compiler recognizes the include guard idiom, and implements the multiple-include optimization the same
>   way as the `#pragma once` directive if no non-comment code or
>   preprocessor directive comes before or after the standard form of the
>   idiom

I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/13339535/11872808